# Parsing Turtle (RDF) from string to array

Tags: php, rdf, easyrdf

How can I parse RDF content (in the Turtle serialization) using [EasyRDF](http://www.easyrdf.org/docs)?  For instance, something like this:

```php
$rdf  = '<subject>  <predicate>  "object0"@en .' ;
$rdf .= "\n" ;
$rdf .= '<subject>  <predicate>  "object1"@en .' ;
$array = turtle_decode(rdf) ;
if ($array["subject"]["predicate"][0]["value"]=="object0")
```

Comment: This function has a wrong description.

Comment: Citation:  `public integer parse(object $graph, string $data, string $format, string $baseUri)`
But it doesn't expect object as first parameter, and notify about some strange error.

Comment: you're citing a different one than what I linked to.  I linked to one with a description: *`public integer parse(string $data, string $format = null, string $uri = null)` Parse some RDF data into the graph object.* **  That looks like it should read RDF content from the string in whatever format you specify, and probably using the uri as the base URI, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP and  EasyRDF:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$data  = '<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11vjz1ynm> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage.date> "2001-02"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYearMonth>  .' .PHP_EOL;
$data .= '<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11vjz1ynm>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage.source> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11x1gf2m6>  .' .PHP_EOL;
$data .= '<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11vjz1ynm>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage>  .' .PHP_EOL;
$data .= '<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11vjz1ynm>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage.rate> 4.5 .' .PHP_EOL;
$data .= '<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11vjz1ynm>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage>  .' .PHP_EOL;

$graph = new EasyRdf_Graph();
$graph->parse($data,'turtle');
$array = $graph->toRdfPhp();
unset($graph);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: While I still think that the answer was easy enough to find in the documentation that this question probably doesn't need to be on Stack Overflow, this is a reasonably good answer that contains full working code.  Be sure to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) after the time limit.